# Iterate through an array in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Right now I have an array.
i.e.
var temp = ['1234', '1235', '1236'];

My html iterates through a JSON object already but I want to add one column in the table that just goes through the array.  For instance I set up a temp column and the first row should have value 1234, the second should have 1235, and the last should have 1236.  Is there a way to do this with ng-repeat?

```
<tbody ng-repeat="ts in allInfo">
                                <td>
                                    {{ts.id}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ts.participant}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{temp}} <-- each row should be the next value in the array.  Right now it outputs the whole array.
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-capitalize">
                                    {{ts.action}}
                                </td>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: As a side note your `tbody` is not well formed: it should be `<tbody> <tr> <td> ... </td> </tr> </tbody>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array has the same number of elements as your object that you are iterating through you can use ng-repeat's `$index` variable which holds the current iteration value.

Also you may want to use `track by` in your ng-repeat statement if your object might have duplicate entries.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="ts in allInfo track by $index">
  <tr>
    <td>
       {{ts.id}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ts.participant}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{temp[$index]}} 
    </td>
    <td class="text-capitalize">
      {{ts.action}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```